# ElasticSearch how can I sort the result of an aggregation with another field of multi-field

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I'm trying to sort the results of an aggregation.
I'm using elasticsearch 1.7.

I use a multi-field with an analyzed field that is asciifolded (themes) and another one that is not analyzed (themes.raw).

This query is working but it is sorted by the unanalyzed field.

Is there a way to do it ?

Mapping analyzer:

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "analyzer_en": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer",
                "filter":  ["stop_custom_en", "stop_orig_en", "asciifolding", "lowercase", "snowball_en" ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping multi_field:

```
"properties": {
    "themes": {
        "type" : "multi_field",
        "fields": {
            "themes": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "analyzer_en"
            },
            "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The aggregations call:

```
"aggregations": {
  "themes": {
    "terms" : {
      "field": "themes.raw",
      "size" : 100,
      "order": {
        "_term": "asc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```